# NSDocument Tab Window Restoration

Tags: swift, macos, nswindowrestoration

### This question deals with tab window restoration in a document-based app.

In an OSX, document-based app, which allows a user to create and convert tab windows, I need to preserve and restore the 'tab' state of each window.

Currently, my document controller restores its documents windows, but not the tab deployment; I get back individual windows; I can merge all back into one, but this is too heavy-handed as their former groupings are lost.

My app document class's - `makeWindowControllers()` function is where I affect the new controllers, whether they should cascade, which I'd read be false, during restore:

```
//  Determine cascade based on state of application delegate
controller.shouldCascadeWindows = <app did receive applicationWillFinishLaunching>
```

so it would be false until it's finished launching.

Finally, my window's class features methods:

```
override func addTabbedWindow(_ window: NSWindow, ordered: NSWindow.OrderingMode) {
    super.addTabbedWindow(window, ordered: ordered)
    window.invalidateRestorableState()
}
override func moveTabToNewWindow(_ sender: Any?) {
    super.moveTabToNewWindow(sender)
    self.invalidateRestorableState()
}

override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    if let tabGroup = self.tabGroup {
        let tabIndex = tabGroup.windows.firstIndex(of: self)
        coder.encode(tabIndex, forKey: "tabIndex" )
        Swift.print("<- tabIndex: \(String(describing: tabIndex))")
    }
}

override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    let tabIndex = coder.decodeInt64(forKey: "tabIndex")
    Swift.print("-> tabIndex: \(tabIndex)")
}
```

to invalidate the window restore state when the tab state is changed.  But I'm not sure with the `NSWindowRestoration` protocol implementation, who or what needs to implement the protocol when a document controller is involved.

I think this is the reason the last function is never called. I get debug output about the encoding but during the next app execution the `restoreStore(coder:)` function is never called.

So who implements this window restore protocol in such an environment I guess is my question, or a decent example doing so.

Comment: In my minimal test app the tabs are restored automatically. Probably not related to the issue but `encodeRestorableState(with:)` and `restoreState(with:)` must call `super`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch but no joy; I have not employed the window restore protocol as I can't see how for doc app?

Comment: Is the question "Why is the build-in state restoration not working?" or is the question "How do I implement my own state restoration?"?

Comment: I do not want to reinvent the wheel, I'm just not sure how to get the tab state restored in a doc based app. If there's code I can tear out, so much the better.

Comment: Does state restoration not work at all without reimplementing or are the windows restored but not the tabs? Maybe creating a [mre] will reveal why it doesn't work. Just checking: is "Close windows when quitting an app" in the system prefs turned off?

Comment: I guess I was led to believe something was needed, but your inference is that no, it should just work, so I'll rip out what I'd added. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My question reveals you not require anything special for a document based app; I've updated my prototype which features this support and environment here [SimpleViewer](https://github.com/slashlos/SimpleViewer), which features Swift5, a document based app supporting tabs.